# Find numbered subdirectories below number X and delete them

Tags: linux, debian, rm, find-util

I have a folder 'masterfolder' that has subfolders with a numbered naming scheme:

`\masterfolder\S01 
\masterfolder\S02
\masterfolder\S03
\masterfolder\S04
\masterfolder\S05`

Now I want to find and delete all folders below a specific number, for example S03. This means, S03, S04, S05 etc should not get deleted, S01 and S02 should get deleted.

I normally use this command to find and delete a specific folder:

```
find "/mnt/USBDRIVE/masterfolder" -type d -name "S02" -exec rm -rf '{}' \;
```

I tried finding a solution myself, but the only method I have found is to delete everything except the number I know I want to keep:

```
find "/mnt/USBDRIVE/masterfolder" -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d -not -name "S03" -exec rm -rf '{}' \;
```

This will keep S03, but delete all others. I want to keep S03 and any other folder with a higher number than S03.

Any ideas appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to solve this.

Since your numbers are zero padded, the easiest way is to just send a list of the directories to a file sorted alphabetically. Then delete the ones you want ignored (they'll all be together), do a global change to add "rm " to the beginning of each line, and run the file as a script.

This will take you less than 30 seconds. Any programmatic solution will take longer.

Comment: This command is the action output of a python program. I would like to do it with a single command like Find..

Comment: This would be an extremely ugly command because you need conditional logic. Much easier to write a script that does what you need and pipe to that.

Comment: Why not just modify the python program?

Comment: Because I am not a programmer, no clue how to do that. It's Flexget btw.